# Edit form has wrong selected value after encrypted value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have private method on controller

```
private

def set_address
   @address = Address.find(params[:id])
end

def city_options
    @city_options = []
    if @address
      @city_options = City.where(province_id: @address.province_id).collect{ |x| [x.name, x.id] }
    end
  end
```

And on views of `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= f.select :city_id, @city_options, { :prompt => I18n.t('prompt.select_city') }, class: 'select-city text address-city' %>
```

It's fine on new form and edit has right selected value, but when I encrypt the id in `city_options` method

```
@city_options = City.where(province_id: @address.province_id).collect{ |x| [x.name, encrypted_id(x.id)] }
```

List of city is shown and value of id is encrypted but wrong selected a value of city, just selected id on top of list.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong value is selected because the saved `city_id` do not match the `encrypted_id` of any select list option.

To get over it you can use `options_for_select` method. Try following if `encrypted_id` method is a helper method

```
<%= f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@city_options, selected: encrypted_id(f.object.city_id)), { :prompt => I18n.t('prompt.select_city') }, class: 'select-city text address-city' %>
```

Check this link http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

If encrypted_id method is a controller method, you have pass currently selected value by encrypting it from controller. Or you can use 
`helper_method :encrypted_id` in controller to make encrypted_id method available in view and can use above mentioned method

Comment: thanks @rohan for answer, but the problem is output of encrypt id is different between encrypt id from `@city_options` and `encrypted_id(f.object.city_id)` although use the same method.

Comment: Have you checked what value is saved in the database. Maybe wrong city_id is saved in the database.
f.object.city_id will give you the saved city_id, print it and see what it returns.
Also check that encrypted_id is defined only at one place.
Can you post encrypted_id method and few city_name and id.